# Engine Running Fast in Park

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, dodge, idle, durango

Never had this issue before but I just started my vehicle and the tac automatically revved up to 1500 rpm when I cranked it. It didn't go back down while in park, it basically idled at about 500 rmp higher than normal. I put it into reverse and it jumped back down to normal speed. When I put it into drive it was fine. When I put it back into park it jumped back up to 1500 rmp, I put it in neutral and it did the same thing. So I put it back in park and shut it off. Interestingly it rolled forward a lot more than usual leading me to believe that it never actually went into park.

This 1998 Dodge Durango usually runs at 1500 rpm in 1st-3rd gear and around 1900 - 2100 rpm in overdrive. At idle it is typically running at or just under 1000 rpm.

So it sounds like a bad ass muscle car when it cranks now but this is weird and as I said, it's never done this before.

I put new tires on yesterday, the day before that I replaced the water pump and thermostat. It had a transmission flush a few weeks ago but it hasn't been slipping. I should mention that putting this thing in reverse has caused the vehicle to lurch a bit usually (but not always). Oh yes and there are no engine codes being thrown at this time.

Any advice/insight much appreciated.

UPDATE: just cranked it again and it functioned as normally... this is (for now) an intermittent issue.

Comment: Is this when it's cold...? Because that sounds normal (engines normally run at an elevated speed when they are cold to heat up to their optimal temperature quicker). The weird part to me is that it didn't do this previously, if so.

Comment: This was from about 3 hours since I ran out for lunch. Yes it should run a bit higher to get going but this was really way to high. And as I said, it didn't do it again after letting it sit for another 20 minutes.

Comment: What does your car usually idle at from a cold start? Most cars I've driven idle well into the 2k+ range at cold start.

Comment: I agree with @Shamtam - I've seen this type of behavior before in many different vehicles. The only thing which is common is when the vehicle is cold, but it doesn't happen all the time. Most of the time, it settles right back down ... other times it will stay revved for 30-45 seconds. I have a feeling if you had let it rest a while before putting it into reverse, you'd have seen the same.

Comment: @AndrewGraham   Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - OP stated the problem became intermittent then OP stopped responding.

Comment: Vote to leave closed - its been a year since OP's last update.